# Position absolute for variable rotated text

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a banner caption with vertical text which I've lined up using `position: absolute;`. However this text is user defined, so as the text changes, the alignment changes. How do I go about positioning this so it stays in the bottom left corner no matter the text?

```css
.banner__wrap {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1180px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.banner__caption {
  bottom: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  left: -50px;
  max-width: 270px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

h4 {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner__wrap">
  <a class="banner__caption" href="www.google.com">
    <h2>this is my heading</h2>
    <h4>this is my cool subheading with a bunch of text</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust `transform-origin` and add a translation like this:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}

.banner__wrap {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1180px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.banner__caption {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 270px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

h4 {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner__wrap">
  <a class="banner__caption" href="www.google.com">
    <h2>this heading</h2>
    <h4>this is  subheading</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the left: -50px; in banner__caption class. I didn't understand why did you use minus. Try to remove it

```
    .banner__caption {
      bottom: 150px;
      background-color: red;
      max-width: 270px;
      position: absolute;
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `position:fixed`. Something like:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.read-up {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
   <div class="read-up">
    Content goes hereeeeeeee
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```